# What is the equivalent of window.location.href in Angular

Tags: angular, stream

In my app users can download a file as a stream from the backend which is a spring boot application, here's the backend code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public StreamingResponseBody download() throws IOException {

    final InputStream fecFile = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\file.zip"));;
    return (os) - > {
        readAndWrite(fecFile, os);
    };
}

private void readAndWrite(final InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
    byte[] data = new byte[2048];
    int read = 0;
    while ((read = is.read(data)) >= 0) {
        os.write(data, 0, read);
    }
    os.flush();
}
```

Inside angular I'm using the following to download the file:

```
window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/download"
```

Which work's fine, but I added a access token based authentication, and I cannot add a token to window.location.href, is there a way to do this in angular, I tried using the **HttpModule** but it's not downloading the file ( it doesn't show any response or error, even though my controller was called ), so is there a way to achive this maybe using jquery or another libreary ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a specific method **(in a service or directly from the component, that's up to you, but I prefer the SOC principle that's why I separed)**

On the service part :

```
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Key': key
    })
  };

  getFile(){

    return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/download", httpOptions )

  }
```

---

and later in your component side:

```
 constructor(private myService: MyTestServiceService ) { }


 downloadFile(data: Response) {

    const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/pdf' }); // pdf is an example
    const url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url);

}

 myMethodToCallMyService() {

   this.myService.getFile()
       .subscribe(

         (data) => {
           this.downloadFile(data)
         },

        (error) => {
           console.log("Server error");
         }

       );
   }
```

Comment: I already specified that I used the HttpModule, but it doesn't work when it's a stream that is comming from the server.

Comment: @Svg_af, in the network tab of your browser console, did you check that it was called ?

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb, I dont know, but i used to download files (multipart ones), anyway, you should try with REST client (e.g: Postman), if that works , angular should so.

Comment: I tried using curl it works fine,FYI  this is a stream and not multipart as I mentioned.

Comment: Same thing, no file is downloading.